# Display data in Edit mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My model returns 11 rows. I am using `ADO.NET` `entity datamodel` i.e `.edmx file`.
I have `stored procedures` and `function` imports in model browsers.
The designer code has `GetMonthlyAwardsToEvaluate_Result`

In my view I just call the model and `scafold template` used I Edit.

I am getting this error...

Exception Details:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List`
1[TestingPMO_RR.Models.GetMonthlyAwardsToEvaluate_Result]', 
 but this dictionary requires a model item of type 
'TestingPMO_RR.Models.Evaluations.EvaluationModel'.
```

### Model.cs:

```
public List<GetMonthlyAwardsToEvaluate_Result> GetMonthlyEvaluation(int intAwardId, 
                                            string strAssociateId, string strStatus)
{
   return ctx.GetMonthlyAwardsToEvaluate(intAwardId, strAssociateId, strStatus).ToList();
}
```

### Controller.cs:

```
public ActionResult ApproveNomination(int ? intAwardId, EvaluationModel eval)
{
   intAwardId = 4;
   eval.AwardId = Convert.ToInt16(intAwardId);
   eval.Status = "PENDING";
   var model = eval.GetMonthlyEvaluation(eval.AwardId, eval.strPendingWith, eval.Status);
   return View(model);
}
```

### View has

```
@model TestingPMO_RR.Models.Evaluations.EvaluationModel
```

Please help.................

The Model returns 11 rows from stored procedure................

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a `List<GetMonthlyAwardsToEvaluate_Result>` to the view because that's what the `GetMonthlyEvaluation` method returns. So your view should be strongly typed to this same model:

```
@model List<TestingPMO_RR.Models.GetMonthlyAwardsToEvaluate_Result>
```

And by the way that's exactly what the error message you got is telling you:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestingPMO_RR.Models.GetMonthlyAwardsToEvaluate_Result]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'TestingPMO_RR.Models.Evaluations.EvaluationModel'